# Altering a Drupal Commerce Form

Tags: commerce, forms

I can't figure out how to alter the drupal commerce form. I created a module with a .module and .info file and have enabled 'devel'. I've also enabled this module. However, when I use the following code, or derivations thereof, no message appears in the message area no matter how many times I refresh the page. I've flushed caches and made sure $messages is set to display on the template.

```
<?php
  function module_name_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
    if($form_id == "commerce_checkout_form_checkout") {
      dpm($form_id);
    }
  }
```

Anyone know what the problem is here?

Comment: for debug : instead of `dpm($form_id)` try `var_dump($form_id);die();`and tell me that getting run or not

Comment: @zhilevan it's magically working today without me changing anything...is it related to cron or something? so strange...

Comment: @zhilevan nevermind, it was user error all along. I was testing with an anonymous user but was seeing the message just fine as admin user :p

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *hook_form_alter()* like this;

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  switch ($form_id) {
    case 'commerce_form':
      ...
    break;
}
```

Comment: this works too. My original works fine it was user error (see my comment above).